# error Laravel - migración por consola --path genera un slash que afecta la ruta ( / \ ) 0 0 votos

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, base-de-datos, migration

estoy poniendo en practica en un ejemplo propio este tema de las migraciones, pero a pesar que pude ejecutar algunas de mis migraciones sin problema, cuando trato de ejecutar una sola migración con este código:

`php artisan migrate --path=\database\migrations\21_06_02_212138_create_payment_concepts_admin_table.php`

me da el siguiente error

`Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem::requireOnce(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\plan/\database\migrations\21_06_02_212138_create_confi_payment_concepts_admin_table.php`

Nótese al lado de la palabra "plan" aparece un /  que se une con \ que es el que he escrito antes database. .. por lo tanto no encuentra la ruta

Buscando errores similares en google recomiendan no colocar colocar \ antes de database,  sin embargo tampoco obtengo resutado ya que sigue apareciendo /  antes de de database.. eso haria que la ruta no fuese correcta.

`Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem::requireOnce(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\plan/database\migrations\21_06_02_212138_create_confi_payment_concepts_admin_table.php'.`

Creo que podría solucionarlo quitando ese / pero no encuentro información al respecto, ni a nivel de código se hacerlo. Si alguien tiene alguna solución o sugerencia para intentar se lo agradecería.

Comment: Puedes probar php artisan migrate --path=database/migrations/21_06_02_212138_create_payment_concepts_admin_table.php quitando la primera barra invertida en database y luego cambiando las otras por '/'

Comment: Saludos, gracias por tu respuesta, esto ya lo intente y no funciona, genera el mismo error, pero con la barra invertida

Comment: pero el error te dice que no se puede abrir el archivo en la ruta tal, revisaste bien el nombre y la ruta? porque lo que te sugerí lo hago todo el tiempo y me a funcionado...